# Why AVX speedup for the following code is not as expected?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, sse, simd, avx

I am programming in AVX using basic _mm256_mul_ps & _mm256_add_ps. And then compare it with normal operation means without using AVX. As i am using float and loading 8 items at the same time in AVX then why my speedup is not more than 3/4 while logically it should be 8 comparing to normal operation. Please have a look at my code and suggest. Thanks

```
inline double timestamp() {
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    return double(tp.tv_sec) + tp.tv_usec / 1000000.;
}

void AVXsum(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE){

        printf("AVX Addition:\n\n");

        for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i+=8){

         __m256 vecA __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_load_ps(&a[i]); // loading 8 values starting from the address of "i"th value of array a

         __m256 vecB __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_load_ps(&b[i]); // loading 8 values starting from the address of "i"th value of array b

         __m256 res __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_add_ps(vecA,vecB); // adding 8 values of array a and b

         _mm256_store_ps(&c[i],res); // storing the value in the "i"th address of another array c

         printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", c[i + 0], c[i + 1], c[i + 2], c[i + 3], c[i + 4], c[i + 5], c[i + 6], c[i + 7]);

        }

        printf("\n");

}

void AVXmul(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE){

        printf("AVX Multiplication:\n\n");

        for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i+=8){

         __m256 vecA __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_load_ps(&a[i]);

         __m256 vecB __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_load_ps(&b[i]);

         __m256 res __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_mul_ps(vecA,vecB);

         _mm256_store_ps(&c[i],res);

         printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", c[i + 0], c[i + 1], c[i + 2], c[i + 3], c[i + 4], c[i + 5], c[i + 6], c[i + 7]);

        }

        printf("\n");

}

void Normalsum(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE){

        printf("Normal Addition:\n\n");

        float add;

        for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i++){

         add = a[i] + b[i];
         c[i] = add;

         printf("%f\t", c[i]);

        }

        printf("\n\n");

}

void Normalmul(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE){

        printf("Normal Multiplication:\n\n");

        float mult;

        for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i++){

         mult = a[i] * b[i];
         c[i] = mult;

         printf("%f\t", c[i]);

        }

        printf("\n");

}

int main(){

    double time, normalsumTime, normalmulTime, avxsumTime, avxmulTime;

    int size;
    printf("Insert the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    // initialization of array and generating random value as per entered size stated above
    float a[size] __attribute__(( aligned(32)));
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        a[i] = (rand()%100)+1;
    }

    float b[size] __attribute__(( aligned(32)));
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        b[i] = (rand()%100)+1;
    }

    int arrsize = sizeof(a) / sizeof (a[0]);
    float c[arrsize] __attribute__(( aligned(32)));


    //the function is called and time is calculated
    time = timestamp();
    Normalsum((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);
    normalsumTime = timestamp() - time;

    time = timestamp();
    Normalmul((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);
    normalmulTime = timestamp() - time;

    time = timestamp();
    AVXsum((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);
    avxsumTime = timestamp() - time;

    time = timestamp();
    AVXmul((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);
    avxmulTime = timestamp() - time;

    //printing the output
    cout << "Normal Sum took " << normalsumTime << " s" << endl;
    cout << "Normal Mul took " << normalmulTime << " s" << endl;
    cout << "AVX Sum took " << avxsumTime << " s" << endl;
    cout << "AVX Mul took " << avxmulTime << " s" << endl;
    cout << "Sum SpeedUP AVX2= " << normalsumTime / avxsumTime << endl;
    cout << "Mul SpeedUP AVX2= " << normalmulTime / avxmulTime << endl;
    cout << "===========================" << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Be careful, you are timing output to the console as well. Output to the console is *slow*. Try doing the output separately, and only time the actual operations you want to time.

Comment: By the way, what is the use of `arrsize`? Shouldn't it be equal to `size`?

Comment: Yeah. The arrsize is double written. Please ignore it. But i did not get your first comment. Would please give me a example / reference?

Comment: You call `printf` multiple times in the functions you benchmark. Including in your loops. Those functions are not very quick. Flushing the output and actually writing it to the console is even slower. All that time will be part of the function call that you benchmark. So you're benchmarking not only the AVX functions, but also the `printf` calls and their writing to the console. That extra time will skew your results. Try just commenting out all `printf` calls and see what you get.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. But unfortunately without printf i am getting ambiguous and false output like timestamp in negative. Please have a look. 
Insert the size of array: 10000
Normal Sum took -2.92202e-008 s
Normal Mul took -2.92202e-008 s
AVX Sum took -2.92202e-008 s
AVX Mul took -2.92202e-008 s
Sum SpeedUP AVX2= 1
Mul SpeedUP AVX2= 1

Comment: @K.Malu: It looks like your benchmarks are too fast for the resolution of the clock source you are using. Note: benchmarking is hard. Really, really hard. You need advanced knowledge of statistics in addition to advanced knowledge of computer architecture, compiler optimizations (for each and every version of each and every compiler you are interested in), the language and the libraries you are using. And lots and lots of experience in how to interpret the results. Benchmarks are typically written by people who are full-time professional benchmarking experts, i.e. do nothing but write …

Comment: … benchmarks all day, every day, for years … and even then, they get it wrong. There's a famous case of a SPEC benchmark (which is **the** industry-standard benchmarking organization) which was supposed to test database performance of a web app stack, but actually tested memory allocator performance of the language runtime.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you are doing a printf for every few instructions.  It makes no sense to benchmark such a thing.

Comment: @DanielLemire if i don't use printf then i get output as mentioned above. So do you have any other way?

Comment: Why would you use a real-time clock like `gettimeofday()` for something that obviously requires a monotonic clock like `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` or `CLOCK_MONOTOMIC_RAW`  or `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems

1. you do not repeat your functions to get the best time. It is essential!
2. your function should not contain functions like `printf`, etc.
3. `_mm256_store_ps` instruction is used in each iteration and your program does not only use the AVX calculation instructions. In the other word, memory-accessing instruction violates the performance and the 8x speedup is not yielded.

I changed your implementation to get more accurate results

```c
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


inline void AVXsum(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE)
{
    for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i+=8){
        //__m256 vecA __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_load_ps(&a[i]); // loading 8 values starting from the address of "i"th value of array a
        //__m256 vecB __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_load_ps(&b[i]); // loading 8 values starting from the address of "i"th value of array b

        __m256 res __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_load_ps(&a[i]),_mm256_load_ps(&b[i])); // adding 8 values of array a and b

        _mm256_store_ps(&c[i],res); // storing the value in the "i"th address of another array c

        //printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", c[i + 0], c[i + 1], c[i + 2], c[i + 3], c[i + 4], c[i + 5], c[i + 6], c[i + 7]);
    }
}

inline void AVXmul(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE)
{
    for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i+=8){
        //__m256 vecA __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_load_ps(&a[i]);
        //__m256 vecB __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_load_ps(&b[i]);

        __m256 res __attribute__(( aligned(32))) = _mm256_mul_ps(_mm256_load_ps(&a[i]),_mm256_load_ps(&b[i]));

        _mm256_store_ps(&c[i],res);

        //printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", c[i + 0], c[i + 1], c[i + 2], c[i + 3], c[i + 4], c[i + 5], c[i + 6], c[i + 7]);
    }
    //printf("\n");
}

inline void Normalsum(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE)
{
    float add;
    for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i++){

        add = a[i] + b[i];
        c[i] = add;

    // printf("%f\t", c[i]);
    }
    // printf("\n\n");
}

inline void Normalmul(float *a, float *b, float *c, int ARR_SIZE)
{
    float mult;
    for (int i=0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i++){

        mult = a[i] * b[i];
        c[i] = mult;

        //printf("%f\t", c[i]);
    }

    //printf("\n");
}
#define size 10000
#define arrsize size
#define NUM_LOOP 1000000

int main(){

    double  normalsumTime, normalmulTime, avxsumTime, avxmulTime;
    struct timespec tStart, tEnd;
    double tTotal , tBest=10000;
    int w =0;// do-while loop counter

    //int size;
    printf("the size of array is: %d \n", size);
    //scanf("%d", &size);

    // initialization of array and generating random value as per entered size stated above
    float a[size] __attribute__(( aligned(32)));
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        a[i] = (rand()%100)+1;
    }

    float b[size] __attribute__(( aligned(32)));
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        b[i] = (rand()%100)+1;
    }

    //int arrsize = sizeof(a) / sizeof (a[0]);
    float c[arrsize] __attribute__(( aligned(32)));

    //the function is called and time is calculated
    printf("\nNormal Addition ... :\n\n");
    do{// this loop repeat the body to record the best time
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tStart);

        //time = timestamp();
        Normalsum((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);
        //normalsumTime = timestamp() - time;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tEnd);
        tTotal = (tEnd.tv_sec - tStart.tv_sec);
        tTotal += (tEnd.tv_nsec - tStart.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;

        if(tTotal<tBest)
            tBest=tTotal;
    } while(w++ < NUM_LOOP);

    normalsumTime = tBest;
    tBest = 100000;
    w=0;

    printf("Normal Multiplication .... \n\n");
    do{// this loop repeat the body to record the best time
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tStart);

        //time = timestamp();
        Normalmul((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);
        //normalmulTime = timestamp() - time;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tEnd);
        tTotal = (tEnd.tv_sec - tStart.tv_sec);
        tTotal += (tEnd.tv_nsec - tStart.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;

        if(tTotal<tBest)
            tBest=tTotal;
    } while(w++ < NUM_LOOP);

    normalmulTime = tBest;
    tBest = 100000;
    w=0;

    printf("AVX Addition....\n\n");
    do{// this loop repeat the body to record the best time
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tStart);

        //time = timestamp();
        AVXsum((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);
        //avxsumTime = timestamp() - time;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tEnd);
        tTotal = (tEnd.tv_sec - tStart.tv_sec);
        tTotal += (tEnd.tv_nsec - tStart.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;

        if(tTotal<tBest)
            tBest=tTotal;
    } while(w++ < NUM_LOOP);

    avxsumTime = tBest;
    tBest = 100000;
    w=0;

    printf("AVX Multiplication ....\n\n");
    do{// this loop repeat the body to record the best time
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tStart);
        //time = timestamp();

        AVXmul((float*)&a, (float*)&b , (float*)&c, arrsize);
        //avxmulTime = timestamp() - time;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tEnd);
        tTotal = (tEnd.tv_sec - tStart.tv_sec);
        tTotal += (tEnd.tv_nsec - tStart.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;

        if(tTotal<tBest)
            tBest=tTotal;
    } while(w++ < NUM_LOOP);

    avxmulTime = tBest;

    //printing the output
    printf("Normal Sum took %lf s\n" , normalsumTime);
    printf("Normal Mul took %lf s\n",  normalmulTime);
    printf("AVX Sum took %lf s \n", avxsumTime);
    printf( "AVX Mul took %lf s\n", avxmulTime);
    printf("Sum SpeedUP AVX= %lf ", normalsumTime / avxsumTime );
    printf("Mul SpeedUP AVX= %lf \n", normalmulTime / avxmulTime );
    printf( "===========================\n");

    return 0;

}
```

The output is:

```
//gcc -O2 
//skylake
Normal Sum took 0.000005 s
Normal Mul took 0.000005 s
AVX Sum took 0.000001 s 
AVX Mul took 0.000001 s
Sum SpeedUP AVX= 4.418283 Mul SpeedUP AVX= 4.491080
```